# POST to a HTTPS service

Tags: java, post, https

I need to know how to `POST` to a `HTTPS` web service. I went through the [tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/java/POST-toHTTPS-url-free-java-sample-program.htm) but it didn't help because it is too old.

Can anyone please help me out by giving me a good tutorial or some sample code to start with?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is not working in the code? I have a HTTP/HTTPS library that I wrote & use, feel free to look at the code. It supports HTTPS so you can step through the code to see how it handles it. Link here: https://github.com/cklab/HTTPConn

Answer (score 2):

Try apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) library. It supports [https](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).

Comment: @user1315906 You can try `HttpPost`

Comment: People on SO aren't going to spoon feed you answers, they expect you take what they have given you, and implement it yourself.  HttpClient is pretty straight forward, use the GET example and apply it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("https://..."); 
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true); 
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

//write the request body
OutputStream requestBody = connection.getOutputStream();
...
requestBody.flush();

//send the request and get the response body
InputStream responseBody = connection.getInputStream();
...
```

Comment: How do i set parameters, like UserName, password etc to the request ?

Comment: They have to be added to the end of the URL.  For example: `URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/page.html?name=Bob%20Smith&age=29");` Remember to encode the parameter names and values using the `URLEncoder` class.

Comment: So if i embed it to the end of the URL then it's going to be a GET request. What i want is to POST. Is there a way i could set values ?

Comment: You have to basically move the query string in the URL to the request body.  For example: `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream()); out.print("name=Bob%20Smith&age=29");`